# Google Cloud Shell is using project=cloud-devshell-dev instead of my actual project, can't find enabled APIs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I created a GCP project to play around with the video-intelligence API. I enabled the API on my project and launched a Cloud Shell.

I then copied the code from [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/video/cloud-client/faces) and followed the README instructions.

However, when I try to run `faces.py` I get this error message:

> StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, Google Cloud Video Intelligence API has
>   not been used in project cloud-devshell-dev before or it is disabled.
>   Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/videointelligence.googleapis.com/overview?project=cloud-devshell-dev
>   then retry

**Why is it pointing to `project=cloud-devshell-dev` and not to my `videointel` project?**

If I `gcloud config list` I can see the correct project and service account. Baffled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a service account and have your application use it for API access, run:

```
  $ gcloud iam service-accounts create my-account
  $ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json
    --iam-account=my-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  $ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json
```

In the second command replace `my-project` with your Project ID.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem.