# App Engine not finding google.auth file in dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-sheets-api

I'm receiving the following error when executing the dev_appserver.py:

```
from google.auth import app_engine
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/    python/runtime/sandbox.py"
, line 1147, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.auth
```

Odd thing is when I deploy the app, it works fine.

I tried:

1. dev_appserver.py MY_DIRECTORY
2. cd /google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/; python dev_appserver.py MY_DIRECTORY
3. python  dev_appserver.py hello_world/
4. Installed updated gcloud components install app-engine-go

Additional info:

1. No virtual env is being used.
2. path to dev_appserver: /google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py
3. I'm using Google's Console Cloudshell
4. Here are the SDK versions:

   - Google Cloud SDK 192.0.0
   - alpha 2017.09.15
   - app-engine-go
   - app-engine-java 1.9.63
   - app-engine-php " "
   - app-engine-python 1.9.67
   - app-engine-python-extras 1.9.63
   - beta 2017.09.15
   - bq 2.0.29
   - cbt
   - cloud-datastore-emulator 1.4.1
   - core 2018.03.02
   - datalab 20180213
   - docker-credential-gcr
   - gcd-emulator v1beta3-1.0.0
   - gsutil 4.28
   - kubectl
   - pubsub-emulator 2018.02.02

Files:

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: flask
  version: 0.12
- name: six
  version: "1.9.0"
```

appengine_config.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
import os

vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'lib'))
```

main.py

```
import logging

from flask import Flask
from sheets import data

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!{}'.format(data)


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    # Log the error and stacktrace.
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return 'An internal error occurred.', 500
```

sheets.py

```
from google.auth import app_engine
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']

spreadsheetId = '<spreadsheet-id>'
rangeName = 'A1:A5'

credentials = app_engine.Credentials(scopes=SCOPES)
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

data = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,     
range=rangeName).execute()
data = data.get('values',[])
```

/lib

```
.
..
apiclient
cachetools
cachetools-2.0.1.dist-info
google
googleapiclient
google_api_python_client-1.5.2.dist-info
google_api_python_client-1.6.5.dist-info
google_auth-1.4.1.dist-info
google_auth-1.4.1-py3.6-nspkg.pth
google_auth_httplib2-0.0.3.dist-info
google_auth_httplib2.py
google_auth_httplib2.pyc
httplib2
httplib2-0.10.3.dist-info
oauth2client
oauth2client-2.2.0.dist-info
oauth2client-4.1.2.dist-info
pyasn1
pyasn1-0.4.2.dist-info
pyasn1_modules
pyasn1_modules-0.2.1.dist-info
rsa
rsa-3.4.2.dist-info
simplejson
simplejson-3.13.2.dist-info
six-1.11.0.dist-info
six.py
six.pyc
uritemplate
uritemplate-0.6.dist-info
uritemplate-3.0.0.dist-info
```

I solve the issue:

The dev_appserver.py was not using the modules in my lib folder. Instead it was using the packages on my computer. To eliminate the issue, I removed all Google packages from my local machine and it works great now.

Comment: What libraries did you vendor in your app's `lib` dir?

Comment: Just added my lib folder.

Comment: Hm, you appear to indeed have `google-auth` installed. Do you see the `google/auth/__init__.py` and `google/auth/app_engine.py` files under `lib`?

Comment: Wait, I see a `google_auth-1.4.1-py3.6...` file in lib - is that a python3 version of the library by any chance? You need a python 2.7 one...

Comment: Thanks @DanCornilescu. Yep, google/auth/__init__.py exists. How would I uninstall google_auth-1.4.1-py3.6..' from the /lib folder and install the python 2.7 version. To be clear, I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: Not entirely sure, I *think* the version of pip may matter. Make sure you don't accidentally run the pip v3. Maybe explicitly call `pip2`?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/issues/169#issuecomment-315417916

I solved this issue by above comment:

Yes, I have the following in appengine_config.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
```

I managed to resolve the module loading issue by using the following instead:

## appengine_config.py

```
import os
import google
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

lib_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/lib'

# Change where to find the google package (point to the lib/ directory)
google.__path__ = [os.path.join(lib_directory, 'google')] + google.__path__

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add(lib_directory)
```

Comment: Thanks @Axa Cheng. I implemented but ran into the next error: `Ena
ble it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=cloud-devshell-dev then re
try. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.">` The API is enabled and the patch also gives me the following error when deploying the app: `    from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder
ImportError: No module named pyasn1.codec.der`. The Sheets API has been enabled for three days.

Comment: I could solve this problem by doing what Kamran said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184869/google-cloud-shell-is-using-project-cloud-devshell-dev-instead-of-my-actual-proj).

Answer (score 0):

I had very likely problem in `from google.auth.crypt import base` and I solved it, so you can try this.

Go to the file that has the import problem, and change manually the:

```
from google.auth import app_engine
```

To the:

```
import app_engine
```