# Demo app from Google NLP not working - "code": 403

Tags: php, nlp, google-cloud-platform, google-natural-language

Could some one help me with sample application from this site: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-php. I did, at least I think I did, everything what is required. And I am constantly getting error 403:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message '{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } } ' in C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\HTDOCS\nlp\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RequestWrapper.php:263 Stack trace: #0 

C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\HTDOCS\nlp\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RequestWrapper.php(168): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) #1 

C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\HTDOCS\nlp\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RestTrait.php(96): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #2 

C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\HTDOCS\nlp\vendor\google\cloud\Language\src\Connection\Rest.php(69): Google\Cloud\Language\Connection\Rest->send('documents', 'analyzeSentimen...', Array) #3 

C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\HTDOCS\nlp\vendor\google\cloud\Language\src\LanguageClient.php(221): Google\Cloud\Language\Connection\Rest->analyzeSentiment(Array) #4 

C:\Users in C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\HTDOCS\nlp\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RequestWrapper.php on line 263
```

Comment: The error you have is `{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }`. It seems you haven't provided a valid API KEY. See how to do it [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys). Also try to follow the tutorial from the github repo where there are more detailed instructions https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/language Tell me if this works please

Comment: Where to put API key in demo code that I gave in a link? A created env. variable with link to json file that I downloaded... I am working on local machine, WIN 10.

Comment: It seems getting the API key doesn't directly apply in this case. Then please follow the instructions here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/language . I ran it from the cloud shell as well as locally from my linux machine and it works. Tell me the results please :-)

Comment: @ Victor Herasme Perez. I installed Composer on my cloud. But I am getting error in console: "Cloud Natural Language API has not been used in project 618104708054 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/ap
is/api/language.googleapis.com/overview?project=618104708054 then retry

Comment: On that link there is a message: The API "language.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it
Tracking Number: 4107029527597204881

Comment: You have to create a service account with permissions for this API. You can create an service account like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44192942/3058302)

Comment: @Mangu It worked. Why it was so hard for Google to say this somewhere in manule. Note: command:  export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json, didn't work. I had to take the key.json form Credentials option.

Comment: Well, the tutorial you were following says that you have to do that. I will post this as an answer, since it solved your issue.

Comment: @Mangu and I did it but using GUI. And it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a service account with permissions for this API, and then download a private key as a JSON file. It is mentioned in the [tutorial you were following](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-php), but you can also do that via the command line like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44192942/3058302).

```
  $ gcloud iam service-accounts create my-account
  $ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json
    --iam-account=my-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  $ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json
```